# minimum-redundancy maximum-relevancy (MRMR) for feature selection

Tags: matlab

I am using a filter measure in feature selection called (MRMR) minimum-redundancy maximum-relevancy. After i run the code below

```
function testselection

    addpath('C:\Users\Desktop\mRMR_0.9_compiled\mi_0.9');
FeaturesFile = dlmread('test.txt')
[x,y]=size(FeaturesFile)
Features=FeaturesFile(:,1:y-1)

classLeble=FeaturesFile(:,y)

[fea] = mrmr_mid_d(Features, classLeble, 5)

end
```

I got the following error

```
Undefined function or variable 'estpab'.

Error in mutualinfo (line 21)
[p12, p1, p2] = estpab(vec1,vec2);

Error in mrmr_mid_d (line 17)
   t(i) = mutualinfo(d(:,i), f);

Error in mrmr (line 9)
[fea] = mrmr_mid_d(Features, classLeble, 5);
```

The code for  mrmr_mid_d as below

```
function [fea] = mrmr_mid_d(d, f, K)
% function [fea] = mrmr_mid_d(d, f, K)
% 
% MID scheme according to MRMR
%
% By Hanchuan Peng
% April 16, 2003
%

bdisp=0;

nd = size(d,2);
nc = size(d,1);

t1=cputime;
for i=1:nd, 
   t(i) = mutualinfo(d(:,i), f);
end; 
fprintf('calculate the marginal dmi costs %5.1fs.\n', cputime-t1);

[tmp, idxs] = sort(-t);
fea_base = idxs(1:K);

fea(1) = idxs(1);

KMAX = min(1000,nd); %500

idxleft = idxs(2:KMAX);

k=1;
if bdisp==1,
fprintf('k=1 cost_time=(N/A) cur_fea=%d #left_cand=%d\n', ...
      fea(k), length(idxleft));
end;

for k=2:K,
   t1=cputime;
   ncand = length(idxleft);
   curlastfea = length(fea);
   for i=1:ncand,
      t_mi(i) = mutualinfo(d(:,idxleft(i)), f); 
      mi_array(idxleft(i),curlastfea) = getmultimi(d(:,fea(curlastfea)), d(:,idxleft(i)));
      c_mi(i) = mean(mi_array(idxleft(i), :)); 
   end;

   [tmp, fea(k)] = max(t_mi(1:ncand) - c_mi(1:ncand));

   tmpidx = fea(k); fea(k) = idxleft(tmpidx); idxleft(tmpidx) = [];

   if bdisp==1,
   fprintf('k=%d cost_time=%5.4f cur_fea=%d #left_cand=%d\n', ...
      k, cputime-t1, fea(k), length(idxleft));
   end;
end;

return;

%===================================== 
function c = getmultimi(da, dt) 
for i=1:size(da,2), 
   c(i) = mutualinfo(da(:,i), dt);
end;
```

And the code for mutualinfo  as follows

```
function h = mutualinfo(vec1,vec2)
%=========================================================
%
%This is a prog in the MutualInfo 0.9 package written by 
% Hanchuan Peng.
%
%Disclaimer: The author of program is Hanchuan Peng
%      at <penghanchuan@yahoo.com> and <phc@cbmv.jhu.edu>.
%
%The CopyRight is reserved by the author.
%
%Last modification: April/19/2002
%
%========================================================
%
% h = mutualinfo(vec1,vec2)
% calculate the mutual information of two vectors
% By Hanchuan Peng, April/2002
%

[p12, p1, p2] = estpab(vec1,vec2);
h = estmutualinfo(p12,p1,p2);
```

Could someone know what is the problem?

Comment: Having a bit of a hard time believing that that is the entire error message...

Comment: I am sorry . I run it again and I got this entire error  'Undefined function or variable 'estpab'.

Error in mutualinfo (line 21)
[p12, p1, p2] = estpab(vec1,vec2);

Error in mrmr_mid_d (line 17)
   t(i) = mutualinfo(d(:,i), f);

Error in mrmr (line 9)
[fea] = mrmr_mid_d(Features, classLeble, 5);
 '

Comment: Please update your question with that. All the useful information is in that missing snippet.

Comment: Also, what do you think the error message is telling you?

Comment: Thanks@MadPhysicist. From the error message I could understand that there are some Undefined functions such as mutualinfo   but the function is defined.

Comment: It directly says "Undefined function or variable **'estpab'**".  From where do you think that the problem is `mutualinfo` being defined or not? I presume you got this function off the internet, and you haven't got all the supporting functions that go with it, or you haven't got them in a location on the matlab path.

Comment: In the path `C:\Users\Desktop\ ` isn't the user missing? Usually windows paths are something like `C:\Users\Username\Desktop\ `  You are probably adding the wrong path, so the program cannot find the function `estpab` at all

Comment: thanks@sembei. Yes i use a path in my code as you stated C:\Users\arwa\Desktop\

Answer (score 0):

If you use this [Mutual information computation](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14888-mutual-information-computation) package, you can see, the `estpab` function compiled only for some platforms (there are estpab.dll for Win32 platform, estpab.mexglx the ELF32 file and estpab.mexmac for Mac).

So, you have to recompile this package for your platform.
First of all you have to configure `mex` building system. Call `mex -setup` and select appropriate compiler.
Than you can recompile the Mutual information computation package by calling `makeosmex`.

Note: If you get some errors during compilation like

> d:\MATLAB work\mi\estcondentropy.cpp(65) : error C2668: 'log' : ambiguous call to overloaded function

you have to modify appropriate line (65 in this example) in appropriate file (estcondentropy.cpp in this example) from the `muInf /= log(2);` to `muInf /= log(2.0);`

Comment: thanks@Andrei. i have done these steps but still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

In the path `C:\Users\Desktop\` isn't the user missing?

Usually windows paths are something like `C:\Users\Username\Desktop\`

You are probably adding the wrong path, so the program cannot find the function `estpab` at all.

Comment: thanks@sembei. Yes i use a path in my code as you stated C:\Users\arwa\Desktop\.

Comment: Then why the code that you posted here has an incorrect path? If your real code is different than the one posted then the error can come from anywhere.